# PHP local value / master value

Tags: php, vhosts

I now have some functions disabled. In PHPInfo, I can see these functions are in 'local value'. 'Master value' is empty. I also disable phpinfo, but I still see the phpinfo. Why? How can I disable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your php.ini file write this line `disable_functions = phpinfo`

Comment: But it's in my .htaccess file. Isn't that possible?

Comment: Only available in php.ini file. More details [here](http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions)